# Absolute centering a flex item loses the button hovers, why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a header for a page that puts the title of the page in the middle and centered absolutely. I tried to do this with flex box and `justify-content:space-between` However as shown below I get the title skewed depending on the buttons width on the right (I've exaggerated that to show the effect)

While I was able to absolutely center the title (using absolute positioning on the h1) as in the example of "Want", a strange side-effect shows up on the buttons- they aren't clickable anymore! I'm flummoxed. What's going on here? How do I center the title and still keep the buttons working (with flex)?

```css
body {
  max-width: 32em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

/* My attempt at keeping h1 absolutely centered on the page width */

h1.want {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <button>Foo</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1 class="want">Want</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Bar</button>
      <button>Bas</button>
      <button>Bat</button>
      <button>Bau</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  The buttons don't work here!
  <nav>
    <div>
      <button>Foo</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Got this</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Bar</button>
      <button>Bas</button>
      <button>Bat</button>
      <button>Bau</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  Buttons work here.
</header>
```

Comment: The `h1` is stacking above the buttons because it's absolute, take a look at [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: I'm not sure how using z-index would help here. Could you elaborate or share an example? Thanks.

Comment: Best solution would be to remove absolute positioning. It will only cause problems Later on.

Comment: Agreed that absolute positioning is a headache- but how would I center the title across the page instead of it sliding according to the width of the buttons on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned **user:Phix**, problem is your headline (with **position: absolute;** property) overlay button. In this case you should add **z-index** to sibling node.

```css
.button-wrapper {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 32em;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2em;
      justify-content: space-between;
      border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
      margin: 20px auto;
    }
    /* My attempt at keeping h1 absolutely centered on the page width */
    
    h1.want {
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
      top: 20px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button>Foo</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 class="want">Want</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Bar</button>
        <button>Bas</button>
        <button>Bat</button>
        <button>Bau</button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    The buttons don't work here!
    <nav>
      <div>
        <button>Foo</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Got this</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Bar</button>
        <button>Bas</button>
        <button>Bat</button>
        <button>Bau</button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    Buttons work here.
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped!

Answer (score 0):

Like @Phix pointed out in the comment, using `position: absolute` with `left: 0` and `right: 0` effectively gives the `h1` a 100% width which then covers the associated buttons so they are unreachable. You can prove this by giving that `h1` a background color (or better yet - use the dev tools in the browser).

If you simply remove all of the styling for `h1.want` you get the desired result without resorting to absolute positioning:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 32em;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2em;
      justify-content: space-between;
      border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
      margin: 20px auto;
    }
    /* My attempt at keeping h1 absolutely centered on the page width */
    /* h1.want {
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
      top: 20px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    } */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div>
        <button>Foo</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 class="want">Want</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Bar</button>
        <button>Bas</button>
        <button>Bat</button>
        <button>Bau</button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    The buttons don't work here!
    <nav>
      <div>
        <button>Foo</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Got this</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Bar</button>
        <button>Bas</button>
        <button>Bat</button>
        <button>Bau</button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    Buttons work here.
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I had wanted to center the title across the page which this solution misses. @yaroslav's solution of applying z-index:1 to the wrappers on buttons works well and retains the intent of keeping title centered.